# Is there any difference between using require of node in template and templateUrl in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, require

Is there any difference between using

1. `require` from node in template
2. `templateUrl` in Angular 2

   ```
   @Component({
       selector: 'hello',
       template: require('./home.html'),
   })

   @Component({
       selector: 'hello',
       templateUrl: './hello.html',
   })
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `template` attribute allows you to define an html template within the javascript file. This can be done for small templates.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'hello',
    template: `<h1>This is part of template`
})
```

The `templateUrl` loads the `./hello.html` file uses it in place of template.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'hello',
    templateUrl: './hello.html',
})
```

The difference would be to use `template` for just small templates and `templateUrl` for files.

Comment: I know the difference between template and templateUrl. The question is why to use require keyword of Node in template ?

Comment: That's what I am doing currently, but still very confusing for me.